# Pandas set values on iloc Nulls

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe and function below. I created a function that will get the coordinates of a 'cell' and put that in a tuple, along with the reason why it was put there. I want this function to also change the value of a certain column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,3,4,5,5,3,1,5,np.NaN], 
                    'B' : [1,0,3,5,0,0,np.NaN,9,0,0], 
                    'C' : [10,0,30,50,0,0,4,10,1,0], 
                    'D' : [1,0,3,4,0,0,7,8,0,1],
                    'E' : [np.nan,'Unassign','Assign','Ugly','Appreciate',
                          'Undo','Assign','Unicycle','Assign','Unicorn',]})
print(df1)
highlights = []
def find_nan(list_col):
    for c in list_col:
        # if column is one of the dataframe's columns, go
        if c in df1.columns:
            # for each index x where column c of the dataframe is null, go
            for x in df1.loc[df1[c].isnull()].index: #appends to the list of tuples
                highlights.append(
                    tuple([x + 2, df1.columns.get_loc(c) + 1, f'{c} is Null in row {x + 2}']))

                df1.iloc[x, df1.columns.get_loc('E')] = f'{c} is blank in row {x + 2}'
find_nan(['A','B']) 
    # using the function above, checks for all nulls in A and B
    # Also places the coordinates and reason in a tuple and changes values of column 'E'

    #output:
    A   B   C   D   E
0   NaN 1.0 10  1   A is blank in row 2
1   NaN 0.0 0   0   A is blank in row 3
2   3.0 3.0 30  3   Assign
3   4.0 5.0 50  4   Ugly
4   5.0 0.0 0   0   Appreciate
5   5.0 0.0 0   0   Undo
6   3.0 NaN 4   7   Assign
7   1.0 9.0 10  8   Unicycle
8   5.0 0.0 1   0   Assign
9   NaN 0.0 0   1   A is blank in row 11
```

What I want to do is add logic that will add the reasons together if `E` is already populated, or simply change the value of `E` if null. Here is my issue: using `df1.iloc` I cannot seem to check for nulls.

`df1.iloc[0]['E'].isnull()` returns `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isnull'` (obviously)

to get around that: I can use if `np.isnan(df1.iloc[0]['E'])` which evaluates to `True`, but if there is a value already in `E` I will get a `TypeError`.

Essentially what I want is this sort of logic within my function:

```
if df1.iloc[x]['E'] is null:
    df1.iloc[x, df1.columns.get_loc('E')] = 'PREVIOUS_VALUE' + f'{c} is blank in row {x + 2}'
else:
    df1.iloc[x, df1.columns.get_loc('E')] = f'{c} is blank in row {x + 2}
```

Expected output from my function on the original dataframe:

```
find_nan(['A','B'])

    A   B   C   D   E
0   NaN 1.0 10  1   A is blank in row 2
1   NaN 0.0 0   0   Unassign and A is blank in row 3
2   3.0 3.0 30  3   Assign
3   4.0 5.0 50  4   Ugly
4   5.0 0.0 0   0   Appreciate
5   5.0 0.0 0   0   Undo
6   3.0 NaN 4   7   Assign and B is blank in row 8
7   1.0 9.0 10  8   Unicycle
8   5.0 0.0 1   0   Assign
9   NaN 0.0 0   1   Unicorn and A is blank in row 11
```

Using Python 3.6. this is part of a bigger project with more functions, hence the 'adding of reasons' and the adding of 2 to the index 'for no apparent reason'

Comment: Tubleweed averted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this was tested using Python 2, but I don't notice anything that would 
prevent it working in Python 3.

```
def find_nan(df, cols):
    if isinstance(cols, (str, unicode)):
        cols = [cols]  # Turn a single column into an list.
    nulls = df[cols].isnull()  # Find all null values in requested columns.
    df['E'] = df['E'].replace(np.nan, "")  # Turn NaN values into an empty string.
    for col in cols:
        if col not in df:
            continue
        # If null value in the column an existing value in column `E`, add " and ".
        df.loc[(nulls[col] & df['E'].str.len().astype(bool)), 'E'] += ' and '
        # For null column values, add to column `E`: "[Column name] is blank in row ".
        df.loc[nulls[col], 'E'] += '{} is blank in row '.format(col)
        # For null column values, add to column `E` the index location + 2.
        df.loc[nulls[col], 'E'] += (df['E'][nulls[col]].index + 2).astype(str)
    return df

>>> find_nan(df1, ['A', 'B'])
    A   B   C  D                                 E
0 NaN   1  10  1               A is blank in row 2
1 NaN   0   0  0  Unassign and A is blank in row 3
2   3   3  30  3                            Assign
3   4   5  50  4                              Ugly
4   5   0   0  0                        Appreciate
5   5   0   0  0                              Undo
6   3 NaN   4  7    Assign and B is blank in row 8
7   1   9  10  8                          Unicycle
8   5   0   1  0                            Assign
9 NaN   0   0  1  Unicorn and A is blank in row 11
```

Comment: replacing the nulls with an empty string was the trick. Although, it's not as 'clean' of a solution as I'd like it to be, I'll take it!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to avoid looping

```
def val(ser):
    row_value = ser['index']
    check = ser[['A','B']].isnull()
    found = check[check == True]
    if len(found) == 1:
        found = found.index[0]
        if pd.isnull(ser['E']) == True:
            return found + ' is blank in row ' + str(row_value + 2)
        else:
            return str(ser['E']) + ' and ' + found +' is blank in row ' + str(row_value+2)
    else:
        return ser['E']



df1['index'] = df1.index


df1['E'] = df1.apply(lambda row: val(row),axis=1)
print(df1.iloc[:,:5])

     A    B   C  D                                 E
0  NaN  1.0  10  1               A is blank in row 2
1  NaN  0.0   0  0  Unassign and A is blank in row 3
2  3.0  3.0  30  3                            Assign
3  4.0  5.0  50  4                              Ugly
4  5.0  0.0   0  0                        Appreciate
5  5.0  0.0   0  0                              Undo
6  3.0  NaN   4  7    Assign and B is blank in row 8
7  1.0  9.0  10  8                          Unicycle
8  5.0  0.0   1  0                            Assign
9  NaN  0.0   0  1  Unicorn and A is blank in row 11
```

**EDIT if multiple columns are nan**

```
def val(ser):
    check = ser[['A','B']].isnull()
    found = check[check].index
    if len(found) == 0:
        return str(ser['E'])
    else:
        one = (str(ser['E'])+' and ').replace('nan and','')
        two = ' and '.join([str(x) for x in found])
        three = ' is blank in row ' + str(ser['index']+2)
        return (one+two+three).strip()



df1['index'] = df1.index


df1['E'] = df1.apply(lambda row: val(row),axis=1)
print(df1.iloc[:,:5])


     A    B     C  D                                 E
0  NaN  NaN   NaN  1         A and B is blank in row 2
1  NaN  0.0   0.0  0  Unassign and A is blank in row 3
2  3.0  3.0  30.0  3                            Assign
3  4.0  5.0  50.0  4                              Ugly
4  5.0  0.0   0.0  0                        Appreciate
5  5.0  0.0   0.0  0                              Undo
6  3.0  NaN   4.0  7    Assign and B is blank in row 8
7  1.0  9.0  10.0  8                          Unicycle
8  5.0  0.0   1.0  0                            Assign
9  NaN  0.0   0.0  1  Unicorn and A is blank in row 11
```

Comment: What happens if a row has more than one `NaN` value?  Also, no need for `== True`, e.g. `check[check]` works just fine.

Comment: @Alexander fair enough, just for fun